# Do perpetual futures have a net unrealized profit or loss (NUPL)?

Tags: trading

Let's say you are trading a perpetual futures derivative of Bitcoin.

I've always understood that these perpetual products have no net unrealized profit or loss, that is, if Bitcoin's market cap increases by 1 trillion dollars, then the net P&L between all perpetual traders will still be zero.

Similarly, if Bitcoin's market cap drops by 100 billion dollars, the net P&L will still be zero.

However my question is simply to ask: is what I said above true?

I couldn't find any definitive answer on the internet, but I'd imagine it's the case because of the 1:1 long:short ratio requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Futures are a zero-sum game. Whatever one side wins, the other loses. Even then it's only *opportunity cost*. If you have a futures contract with another party to buy bitcoin for $50,000, you pay the same amount regardless of the current market price of bitcoin. The seller may need to *buy* bitcoin at market to fulfil the contract, and the buyer can turn around and sell it for market price, and the gains/losses there will cancel. So *in total* there is no P/L with futures contracts, but either *side* of the contract can have profits or losses.

Perpetual futures are the same. If one side gains, the other side loses an equal amount.

Comment: Thanks. To be clear, is this referring to the realized P&L or the unrealized P&L, or both?